# GWT form submission error catching

Tags: exception, gwt

Is there a way to `catch` file upload errors when using the `FileUpload` facility in GWT?

After reading [GWT 2.1 Javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/index.html) I have little hope.

Comment: Can you post your code for uploading file? And also the errors you're receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the GWT Javadoc documentation is somewhat wrong in stating that `onSubmitComplete` is called upon successful form submission:  the callback is triggered even when an error occurs.  The `getResults()` method can be called to watch for `null` value indicating an error condition.